# About Relatively Prime Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am a physics Master student who has been studying abstract algebra by himself.

I have two questions about relatively prime ideals.

My first question goes as follows:

> Let $R$ be a ring, and $I$, $J_{1}, J_{2}, \dots, J_{n}$ be ideals of $R$. If $I$ is relatively prime to any $J_{i}$ for $\forall i=1,2,\dots$, how do I prove that $I$ is coprime to the product $\prod_{i}J_{i}$?

My second question is:

> If $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals of $R$, how to prove that it is equivalent to $I+J$ being contained in no prime ideal?

I found a proof from a Chinese algebra book. But I suspect that the given proof in my Chinese book is incorrect.

I hope you would help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @XiaoyiJing: Do you know about [accepting answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Comment: no I don't. Please elaborate. Did I violate any rules or laws in the place? Or am I impolite to any person?

Comment: @XiaoyiJing: You did not violate any rules. As you are new and you hadn't accepted any answers, I thought that you may not know about the possibility of accepting answers to your questions. I just wanted to inform you of this option. If you would like to know more, there are several questions on meta about accepting answers, for example, [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3399/39599).

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me that rule. I had already accepted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that $R$ has a multiplicative neutral element $1$ (below I show that the claim is false otherwise).

The definition of two ideals $I,J$ being coprime is (AFAIK) that for some elements $i\in I, j\in J$ we have $i+j=1$. This is equivalent to the requirement $I+J=R$, when $R$ is unital (see comments).

So your assumptions imply that to each index $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ there exists elements $i_k\in I, j_k\in J_k$ such that $i_k+j_k=1$.

Hint: Expand the product
$$
1=1^n=(i_1+j_1)(i_2+j_2)\cdots(i_n+j_n).
$$

1. When you are done, can you see that one term is in the ideal
   $J_1J_2\cdots J_n$, and all the other terms are in the ideal $I$?
2. Why does this prove the claim of your first question?

---

If we don't assume that $R$ has a multiplicative neutral element, and attempt to define coprimeness using the condition $I+J=R$, then the claim is actually false. Consider the rng $R=2\Bbb{Z}$. Let $I=4\Bbb{Z}$, $J_1=6\Bbb{Z}$ and $J_2=10\Bbb{Z}$.
We easily see that $2\in I+J_1$ and $2\in I+J_2$ implying that $R=I+J_1$ and
$R=I+J_2$. But here $J_1J_2\subseteq I$, so $I+J_1J_2=I$ is not all of $R$.

Comment: I believe a more "general" definition is $I + J = R$ (which does not require $R$ to have a unity). Not sure how you would re-cast your proof, in this light.

Comment: Dear Jyrki, thank you very much for your hints. But it is the proof that I saw from my Chinese book. I suspect this proof because as I see it, there exists elements $i_{k}\in I$ and $j_{k}\in J$ s.t. $i_{k}+j_{k}=1$ is a consequence of the two ideals being coprime. 

The general definition of two ideals being coprime is that $I+J=R$. I don't see how it can be done from the fact that there exists elements $i_{k}\in I$ and $j_{k}\in J$ s.t. $i_{k}+j_{k}=1$ to the original definition, which is that $I+J=R$. Do you think what I have been confused about makes sense?

Comment: And yes, I was also worrying that R may not be unity, as David said.

Comment: Sorry, for me a ring always has $1$. But that is a matter of definition/faith :-) If the ring $R$ has $1$, then $I+J=R$ clearly implies $1\in I+J$, and consequently those elements $i\in I, j\in J$ exist. Conversely, if $1=i+j$ then $r=r1=ri+rj$ for all $r\in R$ implying $R=I+J$.

Comment: @DavidWheeler: If we allow non-unital rings, then the claim is false. See the update in my answer.

Comment: Hi Jyrki. Thank you so much for your explanations.